# external patitioned table greenplum

Tags: greenplum

I'm trying to create an external, partitioned table in Greenplum.
Getting the following error on executing the create query:

*ERROR: syntax error at or near "PARTITION"*

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE weekly_csv (
product_category text,
tier text,
snapshot_date date
)
LOCATION (
's3://data/weekly_csv/ config=/home/s3.conf')
PARTITION BY RANGE (snapshot_date)
(start('2014-12-05') end ('2020-01-01') every( interval '1 week'))
FORMAT 'csv' (delimiter ',' null as '' header fill missing fields)
ENCODING 'UTF8'
LOG ERRORS SEGMENT REJECT LIMIT 100 ROWS;
```

Not sure if partitioned external tables are a possibility in Greenplum.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: This question might be more suited for dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a partitioned table
2. Create external tables for each week of data
3. Use ALTER TABLE .. EXCHANGE PARTITION to swap the partitions from step 1 with each external table